# How to write a large RDD to local disk through the Scala spark-shell?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, export, rdd

Through a Scala spark-shell, I have access to an Elasticsearch db using the elasticsearch-hadoop-5.5.0 connector.

I generate my RDD by passing the following command in the spark-shell:

```
val myRdd = sc.esRDD("myIndex/type", myESQuery)
```

myRDD contains 2.1 million records across 15 partitions.  I have been trying to write all the data to a text file(s) on my local disk but when I try to run operations that convert the RDD to an array, like myRdd.collect(), I overload my java heap.

Is there a way to export the data (eg. 100k records at a time) incrementally so that I am never overloading my system memory?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `saveAsTextFile` you can pass your filepath as `"file:///path/to/output"` to have it save locally.

Another option is to use `rdd.toLocalIterator` Which will allow you to iterate over the rdd on the driver.  You can then write each line to a file.  This method avoids pulling all the records in at once.

Comment: How would I use toLocalIterator in this case?

Comment: @M.T. `rdd.toLocalIterator.foreach(line => do something with line)`

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs to do this in `PySpark` (to avoid overwhelming their `driver`), here's a complete example:

```
# ========================================================================
# Convenience functions for generating DataFrame Row()s w/ random ints.
# ========================================================================
NR,NC = 100,10 # Number of Rows(); Number of columns.
fn_row = lambda x: Row(*[random.randint(*x) for _ in range(NC)])
fn_df = (lambda x,y: spark.createDataFrame([fn_row(x) for _ in range(NR)])
                          .toDF(*[f'{y}{c}' for c in range(NC)]))
# ========================================================================
```

Generate a `DataFrame` with `100-Rows` of `10-Columns`; containing integer values between `[1..100)`:

```
>>> myDF = fn_df((1,100),'c')
>>> myDF.show(5)
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| c0| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6| c7| c8| c9|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 72| 88| 74| 81| 68| 80| 45| 32| 49| 29|
| 78|  6| 55|  2| 23| 84| 84| 84| 96| 95|
| 25| 77| 64| 89| 27| 51| 26|  9| 56| 30|
| 16| 16| 94| 33| 34| 86| 49| 16| 21| 86|
| 90| 69| 21| 79| 63| 43| 25| 82| 94| 61|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Then, using `DataFrame.toLocalIterator()`, "stream" the `DataFrame` `Row` by `Row`, applying whatever post-processing is desired. This avoids overwhelming `Spark driver` memory.

Here, we simply `print()` the `Row`s to show that each is the same as above:

```
>>> it = myDF.toLocalIterator()
>>> for _ in range(5): print(next(it)) # Analogous to myDF.show(5)
>>>
Row(c0=72, c1=88, c2=74, c3=81, c4=68, c5=80, c6=45, c7=32, c8=49, c9=29)
Row(c0=78, c1=6, c2=55, c3=2, c4=23, c5=84, c6=84, c7=84, c8=96, c9=95)
Row(c0=25, c1=77, c2=64, c3=89, c4=27, c5=51, c6=26, c7=9, c8=56, c9=30)
Row(c0=16, c1=16, c2=94, c3=33, c4=34, c5=86, c6=49, c7=16, c8=21, c9=86)
Row(c0=90, c1=69, c2=21, c3=79, c4=63, c5=43, c6=25, c7=82, c8=94, c9=61)
```

And if you wish to "stream" `DataFrame` `Row`s to a local file, perhaps transforming each `Row` along the way, you can use this template:

```
>>> it = myDF.toLocalIterator() # Refresh the iterator here.
>>> with open('/tmp/output.txt', mode='w') as f:
>>>    for row in it: print(row, file=f)
```